# which restlet edition should I use to create website

Tags: java, restlet

I want to create a java rest API using the Restlet framework. I want my API to be available over the internet so that the front-end applications can be mobile phone apps for iPhone or Android or websites. My server is likely to be tomcat (I have not checked yet if glassfish will do).

My question is this: which edition of Restlet do I use: the Java SE or the Java EE Edition? Here is a link that describes them very succinctly: http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/171-restlet/344-restlet.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one: Java EE edition. It has extra code in it to connect to enterprise containers.

Source [here](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/275-restlet/312-restlet.html):

> This edition is aimed for development and deployment of Restlet
>   applications inside Java EE application server, or more precisely
>   inside Servlet containers such as Apache Tomcat.

Comment: Under what circumstance would I ever use the SE edition to build a Restlet API? What I am asking is why does an SE edition exist at all? I found that a bit confusing.

Comment: My guess is that it provides additional versatility. It probably precedes the EE version as well. I don't know why you want to either, but you could (for instance) embed a Restlet server in a front end application, perhaps Android amongst other thoughts.

Comment: Java SE edition is ideal when light footprint is preferred, or during development phases when a full Java EE container is too heavy. Another way to ask, is why do you need a full blow Java EE application server ?